# How to have reference to an accordin in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm working with an accordion that has 10 grids inside of it. So basically I would like to access each grid in the accordian but not really sure how to accomplish that in ExtJS.

**Example:** If I want to target a grid I can do this:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('grid');
```

But if I use the above code it will target all of the grids from the UI and I don't want that. I ONLY want to target the grids from my accordian.

```
   layout: { 
            type: 'accordion', 
            animate: false, 
            fill: false, 
            hideCollapseTool: false, 
            collapseFirst: false, 
            titleCollapse: false, 
            multi: true,
            overflowHandler: 'scroller'
        }
```

Any ideas how to do that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use the query method on the accordion (or any container) to find the matching components within it. `accordion.query('grid');`. See [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.container.Container.html#method-query).

Comment: @chrisuae but how do I reference the accordion ? I tried this and it doesn't work: me.down('accordion').query('grid')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First thing `accordion` is not an `xtype`.

[Accordion](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.layout.container.Accordion.html) is a layout that manages multiple Panels in an expandable accordion style such that by default only one Panel can be expanded at any given time.

> As you ONLY want to target the grids from your `accordian`

if you have created your custom `xtype:'accordion'` then you can get like this `me.down('accordion').query('grid')` if `me` contain `xtype:'accordion'`.

If you have define [reference](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-reference) then you can get like this [lookupReference](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.app.ViewController.html#method-lookupReference) using controller or [lookupReference](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.container.Container.html#method-lookupReference) using view.

Here I have created an small [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/298r) demo. Hope this will help you.

```
//create grid
Ext.define('DemoGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    xtype: 'demogrid',
    store: {
        fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
        data: [{
            name: 'Lisa',
            email: 'lisa@simpsons.com',
            phone: '555-111-1224'
        }, {
            name: 'Bart',
            email: 'bart@simpsons.com',
            phone: '555-222-1234'
        }, {
            name: 'Homer',
            email: 'homer@simpsons.com',
            phone: '555-222-1244'
        }, {
            name: 'Marge',
            email: 'marge@simpsons.com',
            phone: '555-222-1254'
        }]
    },
    columns: [{
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name'
    }, {
        text: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        text: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone'
    }],
    flex: 1
});

//controller
Ext.define('DemoCnt', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.demo',

    onButtonClick: function (button) {
        var accordion = this.lookupReference('demoAccordion'); //if your Accordion Layout is inside of panel/coantainer then you can use like this {this.lookupReference(your refrence name)}.

        this.doGetAllGrid(accordion);

        /* var panel = button.up('panel');
         panel.down('[reference=demoAccordion]');

         panel.down('panel') also we get like this

         panel.down('panel[reference=demoAccordion]') also we get like this
         */

    },

    doGetAllGrid: function (accordion) {
        var data = [];
        //{accordion.query('grid')} return all grid as Accordion contain
        Ext.Array.forEach(accordion.query('grid'), function (item) {
            data.push('<b>' + item.title + '</b>');
        });
        Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Your all grid title is below :-<br>' + data.join('<br>'));
    }

});

//Accordion Layout panel
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'Accordion Layout',
    width: '100%',
    controller: 'demo',
    height: 700,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        reference: 'demoAccordion',
        layout: {
            // layout-specific configs go here
            type: 'accordion',
            animate: false,
            fill: false,
            hideCollapseTool: false,
            collapseFirst: false,
            titleCollapse: false,
            // multi: true,
            overflowHandler: 'scroller'
        },
        defaults: {
            xtype: 'demogrid'
        },
        items: [{
            title: 'Grid 1'
        }, {
            title: 'Grid 2'
        }, {
            title: 'Grid 3'
        }, {
            title: 'Grid 4'
        }, {
            title: 'Grid 5'
        }, {
            title: 'Grid 6'
        }, {
            title: 'Grid 7'
        }, {
            title: 'Grid 8'
        }, {
            title: 'Grid 9'
        }, {
            title: 'Grid 10'
        }],
    }, {
        xtype: 'demogrid',
        margin:'10 0',
        title: 'Grid 11 will not inside of Accordion Layout '
    }],
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Get All Grid',
        height: 50,
        padding: '0 35',
        style: 'background: transparent;border: 2px solid #737373cc;',
        handler: function () {
            var panel = this.up('panel');
            panel.getController().doGetAllGrid(panel.down('[reference=demoAccordion]')); //Just call only common method of controller to get all grid.
        }
    }, {
        text: 'Get All using controller method with a reference',
        height: 50,
        padding: '0 35',
        style: 'background: transparent;border: 2px solid #737373cc;',
        handler: 'onButtonClick'
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```